# Assigning Default/AcceptButton values inside GroupBox Controls

Tags: vb.net, groupbox

Is there any function in Visual Basic .NET to make a button inside a `GroupBox` act as the `AcceptButton`, but only for the other form controls it shares the `GroupBox` with?

I'm only seeing the option on the main form and there doesn't seem to be anything on the Enter Event.

Has anyone tried writing code for this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try resetting the form's AcceptButton property based on entering and leaving the GroupBox:

```
Private Sub GroupBox1_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
                            Handles GroupBox1.Enter
  Me.AcceptButton = Button2
End Sub

Private Sub GroupBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
                            Handles GroupBox1.Leave
  Me.AcceptButton = Button1
End Sub
```

Comment: Works for me. Maybe worth extending so that you can pass in the button you want per GroupBox.